# Google Cloud Pub/Sub Triggers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm pretty new to GCP. I need to trigger a Cloud Function(CF) when a message is published to pub/sub topic. I can do that easily when both pub/sub and CF are in the same project. But in my case, the pub/sub topic and CF are in two different projects. Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Write a pubsub function in project A that proxies the message payload to a topic in  project B, and write a separate function to handle it there.  You can't simply write functions that respond to topics in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

What Doug said in their comment.

You want to go Pub/Sub in Project A to GCF in Project B means you have a GCF in Project A that writes to Project B's Pub/Sub (you'll need to get a service account for Project B in the requirements for Project A's GCF). Then your GCF in Project B can pick up its own Pub/Sub that had the message forwarded to it from the GCF in Project A.

Adds a little bit of latency of course since it's multiple hops, but as long as the projects are in the same region, it should be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the "proxy" solution of my 2 peers (Gabe and Doug). However, there is a lack of explanation, and I have another solution!

The problem is: you can't create a Cloud Function Topic triggered from a topic in another project. The topic MUST be in the same project as the Cloud Function (that's why a Cloud Function proxy is required).

But, you can also deploy your Cloud Function in [HTTP triggered](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) and then create a [PubSub HTTP Push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) to the Cloud Function in any project.

You can deploy your [function in private mode](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing) (--no-allow-unauthenticated mode) and grand the [PubSub subscription service account](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#authentication_and_authorization) the right to call the Cloud Function to increase the security.